# UWP Telerik UI How to add convert into RadCartesianChart's Vertical Axis?

Tags: data-binding, telerik, uwp-xaml, telerik-charting

I had been puzzled for a long time as my RadCartesianChart seems to reject to add a convert above on it's axis.

Here is what I had written:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
   <telerik:DateTimeContinuousAxis Maximum="{x:BindViewModel.Infos.MaxmumDatetime}"     
      Minimum="{x:Bind ViewModel.Infos.MinmumDatetime}"                                                           
      GapLength="0.5"
      MajorStep="6"
      MajorStepUnit="Hour"
      LabelFormat="{}{0,0:HH:mm}"
      x:Name="HorizontalAxis"
      Title="Datetime of request"/>
      </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
      <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
      <telerik:LinearAxis Title="Request Interval" x:Name="VerticalAxis">     
</telerik:LinearAxis>
```

and data binding part:

```
<telerik:BarSeries ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Infos.Logs,Mode=TwoWay}" PaletteMode="Series"> 

<telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
      <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="requestTime" />
   </telerik:BarSeries.ValueBinding>
      <telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
      <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="createTime"/>
   </telerik:BarSeries.CategoryBinding>
</telerik:BarSeries>
```

What should I do ??

Comment: My Email : 22955601@qq.com

Comment: Could you provide the minimal complete code or a  project to see the issue and what you really want to achieve?

Comment: OK, I will send an email included my code to u if u can provide your email address.

Comment: @BinXiao It's not allowed for us to provide email address or send you email since we don't handle email support. Please submit your sample to some online drive and then post back the url. And specific to your issue, what do you want to convert? Have you tried to check the source code from Github yourself?

Comment: Sorry for my foolish behavior, I will provide my code as soon

Comment: Here is my project : [→ to github project](https://github.com/hddevteam/ServerMonitor-for-UWP)